# Is it possible to connect to Oracle Database through OCI using a reverse proxy?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to connect to Oracle Database (11g) through OCI using some kind of reverse proxy?
Right now, I have to connect to a virtual machine using RDP, this VM is hosted in my client network, and I have to develop on it.
I would like to connect to my client database from my computer so I can use SQL Navigator and develop applications faster and not on that VM.

Comment: Do you have a Linux box handy on the same internal network?

Comment: Yes, there are many servers running on Linux on the same internal network.

Comment: Before anything else, check with your security people that what you're trying is allowed. As you've described it, you're effectively trying to punch a hole in your client's setup - this is grounds for dismissal in a bunch of situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your database remotely by establishing a *ssh tunnel*.

```
#ssh -N -L [local port]:[database host]:[remote port] [username]@[remote host]
ssh -N -L 9998:x.x.x.x:1521 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_aws.pem ec2-user@x.x.x.x
# in a new terminal, login locally. (you are now going into the tunnel)
sqlplus user/pass@localhost:9998/XE
```

Use *putty* if you are on Windows.